# FFMpegCore C# read bytes from file

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am trying to read byte array or stream from mp4/h264 file using **"FFMpegCore"** library.
I am trying to read file and store it into `fileStreamOnlyWithMedia` but I have error

> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument"

```cs
var fileStreamOnlyWithMedia = new MemoryStream();

FFMpegArguments
   .FromFileInput(filePath)
   .OutputToPipe(new StreamPipeSink(fileStreamOnlyWithMedia), options => options
      .WithVideoCodec(VideoCodec.LibX264).WithoutMetadata().ForceFormat("mp4").WithFastStart()).ProcessSynchronously();

fileBytes = fileStreamOnlyWithMedia.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the mp4 container requires seeking (because of the required ordering of the content inside the file), which isn't possible when ffmpeg is outputting to a pipe.

You could try with vp9 and mkv instead

For more information, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/760287)